# Debugging with NUnit; ignore exceptions and only pausing at breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

I'm debugging my unit tests by attaching the `nunit-x86.exe` process, which is working splendidly. Some of my tests are asserting that an exception is thrown, upon which the debug is pausing and letting me know something *went wrong*. With any normal debug process this would be handy, however when unit testing it's a bit of a pain. So I ask:

**Is there any way, whilst debugging, to only pause at breakpoints, and ignore exceptions?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Visual Studio menu `Debug > Exceptions...`

Uncheck all items from column `Break when an exception is Thrown`. You can also disable breaking on unhandled exceptions there.